# How to create a function with a typed callback which ensures all callback parameters are passed to it

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

Given a function that accepts a callback with typed arguments, how can I make sure it doesn't allow functions without arguments.

I have added a sample code snippet that represents my problem

```ts
function x(cb: (a: number) => any) {
  cb(12)
}
x((a: number) => 1) // OK
x(() => 1) // OK
x((a: string) => 1) // Error: Argument of type '(x: string) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: number) => any'.
```

The second line should generate an error as this doesn't pass a complete list of parameters required by the callback

I want to enforce that every usage of function `x` should have all parameters in the callback as specified in the original function signature

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABADwBQQEYC5GoIY5ggC2GApgE4CUiAvAHyJ5gCeNA3gLABQiimqAIwAmKjwC%20PNPkIly1Oo0E0A9CsQB5ANJTUqGg0TLEazTu7SCiAM5QKMMAHMDS1eoCiFCnAo4AghSOJGRgUIhwwIhQLAAOZIgA5KjIOLb2Ti6IRKSUCYgw1llwYXjW1jCOYHgYADbxUHCIMXgUeMRkUJThkdFxiTJZcpSZzCwJAHRAA)

Comment: I took the liberty and have modified your question, feel free to roll it back if you want

Comment: Cool, hope somebody can help. I've removed my "answer"

Comment: This goes against the general behavior of Typescript.  It might be impossible, or it might just be complicated!

Comment: Got it! Writing an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general behavior of TypeScript is that it's okay to have a function which requires less arguments than what's provided.  For example, when you have an `onClick` function `(e: MouseEvent) => void` it's fine to provide a function which does not use `e`.

So we have to get tricky here in order to disallow `() => 1` as this function **is assignable** to `(a: number) => any`.

#### Solution

```
function x<T extends (a: number) => any>(cb: T & ([] extends Parameters<T> ? never : T)) {
  cb(12)
}
x((a: number) => 1) // OK
x(() => 1) // Error: Argument of type '() => number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
x((a: string) => 1) // Error: Argument of type '(x: string) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: number) => any'.
```

#### Explanation

I am using a generic type parameter `T` to represent the callback argument of our function `x`.  We say that `cb` must be `T`, but we also impose an additional rule.  We need to check the arguments of the callback which are `Parameters<T>`.  If an empty array `[]` is assignable to these arguments (`[] extends Parameters<T>`), we say that `cb` must be `T & never`.

`T & never` is an impossible condition which causes us to get the red-underlined error on your second example.  Here `T` is inferred as `() => number` so `cb` must be `never`.  Therefore we get an error *"Argument of type '() => number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'."*

---

Your example function `x` doesn't return anything, but it could `return cb(12)` and get the correct return type based on the return type of the callback `cb`.

```
function x<T extends (a: number) => any>(cb: T & ([] extends Parameters<T> ? never : T)): ReturnType<T> {
  return cb(12)
}
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/NrKQ5m)